# Render express response in html element using fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch

I'm currently working on a little node/express project that displays the bcyrpt hashed value of a users input. I can get the hashed value to display in the servers console.log, but I'm having a hard time injecting the value into the frontend's div that I designated for the results.

**index.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bcrypt Input Page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="/submit-form" method="POST">

        <label for="string"><b>String Input:</b></label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="string" required size="40" id="string">
        <input type="submit" value="Hash/Salt it!" id="submit-button">
    </form>

    <section id="responseArea">

    </section>
    <script src="/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express()
const path = require('path')
const { hashesString, passwordCheck } = require('./bcryptUtil');

app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}))

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

app.post('/submit-form', (req, res) => {
    const userInput = req.body.string;
    hashesString(userInput)
        .then((output) => {
            console.log(output);
            res.send(JSON.stringify(output))


        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
})


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/index.html'));
    //line 10 suffices, you don't need the next line
    //res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './public/script.js'))
})



app.listen(3003);
```

**script.js**

```
const area = document.getElementById("responseArea")

//area.innerHTML = `<h1> Hello World! </h1>`;

const button = document.getElementById("submit-button");

button.addEventListener("click", launchAjax);

/* const launchAjax = (formData) => {
    fetch("/submit-form", {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(formData)
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(responseJSON => {
            area.innerText = responseJSON;
        })
} */

const launchAjax = fetch('/submit-form')
    .then((res) => res)
    .then((data) => {
        area.textContent = data;
    })
```

So my question is, how do I use fetch to receive the response sent by the post request from the server and render it in the section element with the id of "responseArea" in the index.html file?

Also, there's a separate file with the bcrypt business logic, but I'm not including it because I don't think it's needed and it would just add clutter. If you do find you need it, feel free to ask though.

Comment: In script.js `.then((res) => res)` isn't doing anything.  Also, your /submit-form on the server is a POST handler, but you are doing a GET call from your script.js.  Not sure which you intend to use.

Comment: Your commented-out code in scriot.js looks like it's more likely to work, as it's doing a POST.  I'd suggest using that and logging the output in the browser.

Comment: Do you only want to use `fetch` or is another solution acceptable to you?

Comment: @user2740650, I thought I'd add a res.send method to the post route just to have the server send back whats being processed instead of making a separate route/method. I guess I should make a get route to separate the functionality?

Comment: @SPARTACUS5329, I'd like to use fetch, but I'm open to alternative solutions. Will your solution involve axios?

Comment: @user2740650. re:POST in script.js commented out code: I was wondering about just using fetch to post (as opposed to the form method/action attributes in the html file) and then wait for a response from the server. I found that code in another s/o post but I just decided to make a fetch method that would wait for receiving a response from the server.

Comment: You can use GET or POST, you just have to make sure the server and client are using the same thing.  Right now your server supports POST but your client is doing a GET, so that GET won't invoke your POST handler.  It will just fall back to your default GET handler.

Comment: @user2740650, well, yes, I'd like to request the hashed string from the server. Or how would I receive a response from the server with that data?

Answer (score 2):

You can use JQuery to create a POST request like this

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: `/route`,
  data: { /* as an object */ },

  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  },

  error: function (data) {
    console.error(data);
  },
});
```

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>`

Add this tag to use JQuery and after this line, reference the file where you are adding the previous code

**This is not a very standard approach but it'll work properly.**

**NOTE**: The script tag for JQuery might be old, so if you face a problem I suggest getting access to the latest JQuery URL

Comment: Lol and I thought jQuery was dead :)

Answer (score 1):

Id try this

```
const launchAjax = () => {
    fetch('/submit-form',
        { method: 'POST' })
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then((data) => {
            area.textContent = data;
        })
}
```